# Mapping an array of objects that compares each object to an array of ids

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have been working all day for this but I can't still solve it. So I'm using tmdb and I have their array of genre objects which is laid out like this:

```
  {
    id: 28,
    name: "Action",
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: "Adventure",
  }, ....
```

And I'm looking to compare it to the movie I pass on to a movie component which has an object "genre_ids" that is an array of genre ids and it is laid out like this

`genre_ids: [14, 28, 12]`

I have this in my return :

```
                  (genre, index) =>
                    genre.id === showModal?.genre_ids[index] && (
                      <li className="border-2 2xl:border-4 inline rounded-xl px-2">
                        {genre.name}
                      </li>
                    )
                )}
```

But it doesn't work as I want it to. I'm hoping to render/return the genre names of each movie. If anyone could help me that'd be awesome. I'm using JSX components, react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try something like this using array.filter()

```
  const genre_ids = [14 , 20];
  const genre = [{id: 14, name: "action"}, {id: 20, name: "drama"}, {id: 25,name: "sci-fi"}]
  // Will store [{id: 14, name: "action"}, {id: 20, name: "drama"}] in filteredGenre
  const filteredGenre = genre.filter(element => genre_ids.includes(element.id))
```

You can then map over filteredGenre